# What is the purpose of the Count parameter of TStream.WriteData and TStream.ReadData?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

The `TStream` class contains many overloads of `WriteData` that are of this form:

```
function WriteData(const Buffer: Int32; Count: Longint): Longint; overload;
```

There are overloads for all the usual suspects, `AnsiChar`, `Char`, `UInt32`, `Double` and so on. Similarly for `ReadData`. I'm trying to understand what purpose the `Count` parameter serves. The implementation of the overload mentioned above is as follows:

```
function TStream.Skip(Amount: Integer): Integer;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  P := Position;
  Result := Seek(Amount, soCurrent) - P;
end;

function TStream.WriteData(const Buffer: Int32; Count: Longint): Longint;
const
  BufSize = SizeOf(Buffer);
begin
  if Count > BufSize then
    Result := Write(Buffer, BufSize) + Skip(Count - BufSize)
  else
    Result := Write(Buffer, Count)
end;
```

I can obviously see what this code does, but I cannot understand why it would make sense to perform a partial write. Why would it ever make sense to call this function with `Count < BufSize`? The behaviour then is very odd.

Does anyone know why these overloads were added and what purpose they are intended for? Naturally I've looked at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStream.WriteData) which has nothing to say about these methods.

---

As an aside I will submit bug report concerning this line:

```
Result := Write(Buffer, BufSize) + Skip(Count - BufSize);
```

It is a mistake to assume that the call to `Write` will occur before the call to `Skip`. The evaluation order of the operands to the `+` operator is not defined. This code should rather be written like this:

```
Result := Write(Buffer, BufSize);
inc(Result, Skip(Count - BufSize));
```

Comment: You never wanted to write a half of a Unicode char :) ?

Comment: @TLama At least on a little endian machine it would be the right half!

Comment: After a quick search through source code that comes with Delphi XE3 I found that only TclientDataset component uses WriteData with aditional size parmaeter when writing data into stream. Why does it use this in such way? I'm not sure. Maybe you will get better understanding of this by yourself after checking the TClientDataset code.

Comment: I actually do this quite a lot of times when having a dynamic array of a certain size but I only want to write parts of it to a file e.g. If I have a filtered signal in an array which has swing in and out data buffers and I only want to write the real data (without that overhead) I often reference the complete dynamic array (or any other pointer to a buffer) and provide the count of really written data.

Comment: @mrabat That's not what is happening here. Here the code is capable of writing partial values. So, only 3 bytes of an integer, or even worse, <8 bytes of a double.

Comment: That's the oddest thing i've seen in a while. Just ran into that issue because I assumed what would be the natural, most intuitive meaning of a `count` parameter for a `Write` method. Turned out that I underestimated the creativity of certain API designers once more.

Answer (score 1):

Theory crafting

*if* TStream predate the introduction of the `overload` keyword (Delphi 3 IIRC), they probably introduced a single method to write integer that was probably int32.  When calling the function with a "byte" variable, it would get passed to the function as Integer, and then the Count parameter would only allow to write a single byte. Now they support this for backward compatibility purpose.

In some cases(like next one), supporting `Count < Bufsize` is indeed especially silly :

```
function WriteData(const Buffer: Int8; Count: Longint): Longint; overload;
```

Another justification would be in the next situation when a variable only need to be saved to stream as an Int8 but is worked on as a Int32 during program execution (because it is passed to a function that only takes a `var : Int32` as parameter).

```
procedure SomeProc(var MyInt : Integer);

procedure DoSomeStream;
var
  iVal : Integer;
//  bVal : ShortInt;
begin
  SomeProc(iVal);
  Stream.WriteData(iVal, SizeOf(Byte));
  //Instead of
//  SomeProc(iVal);
//  bVal := iVal;
//  Stream.WriteData(bVal)
end;
```

I'm not saying it's required (can be worked around) but in some corner case situation, it could be useful.

Comment: > ".. backward compatibility .." > .ReadData .WriteData are introduced way after "overload", in XE3.

Comment: `TStream` was pretty stable until the next gen compilers started appearing and then it all kicked off. So I don't think this is it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yep, some weird and broken code has been introduced, so it is hard to tell why is this one actually there.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that this code enables you to write some data and than skip to a position far behind the data.

e.g. you have a stream containing multiple integers and you want to overwrite every 5th, you can do it with:

```
mData := 15;
WriteData(mData, SizeOf(mData) * 5);
```

Comment: That's the part that I understand. Why would it make sense to perform a partial write? In the question I wrote: *"Why would it ever make sense to call this function with Count < BufSize?"*